# Issue with NFC Tag (NTAG213) Becoming Unwritable Without Storing Desired URL Data

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, nfc, nfc-p2p

I've been working on a project involving NTAG213 NFC tags. My objective is to write a specific URL to these NFC tags and then lock them to prevent any further modification or overwriting. However, I'm encountering a peculiar issue: after executing my Python script, the NFC tags indeed become unrewritable, but the URL data I intended to store on them doesn't appear to be written. I'm looking for insights or solutions as to why this might be happening.

Here's the Python script I'm using:

```
from smartcard.System import readers
from smartcard.util import toBytes
from smartcard.Exceptions import NoCardException

def create_ndef_uri_record(url):
    # Create an NDEF record for the URL
    uri_prefix_code = 0x03  # 0x03 for 'http://'
    ndef_header = [0x03, len(url) + 5, 0xD1, 0x01, len(url) + 1, 0x55, uri_prefix_code]
    ndef_uri_field = [ord(c) for c in url]
    ndef_end = [0xFE]
    return ndef_header + ndef_uri_field + ndef_end

def write_to_card(connection, data, start_page=4):
    # Write data to the card
    for i in range(0, len(data), 4):
        page = start_page + i // 4
        command = [0xFF, 0xD6, 0x00, page, 4] + data[i:i+4]
        response, sw1, sw2 = connection.transmit(command)
        if sw1 != 0x90 or sw2 != 0x00:
            raise Exception(f"Error writing to card: SW1={sw1}, SW2={sw2}")

def lock_nfc_tag(connection):
    # Lock the card to prevent overwriting
    # For NTAG213, lock the card by setting lock bits and OTP
    lock_command = [0xFF, 0xD6, 0x00, 0x2A, 0x04, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0F, 0xE0]  # Example lock command
    otp_command = [0xFF, 0xD6, 0x00, 0x03, 0x04, 0xBD, 0x04, 0xBD, 0x04]  # Example OTP setting command

    # Send lock command
    response, sw1, sw2 = connection.transmit(lock_command)
    if sw1 != 0x90 or sw2 != 0x00:
        raise Exception(f"Error locking card: SW1={sw1}, SW2={sw2}")

    # Send OTP setting command
    response, sw1, sw2 = connection.transmit(otp_command)
    if sw1 != 0x90 or sw2 != 0x00:
        raise Exception(f"Error setting OTP: SW1={sw1}, SW2={sw2}")

    print("Card permanently locked and OTP set")

def main():
    url = "example.com"

    card_readers = readers()
    if not card_readers:
        print("No NFC card readers found")
        return

    reader = card_readers[0]
    connection = reader.createConnection()

    try:
        connection.connect()
        print("Connected to NFC card successfully")
        ndef_record = create_ndef_uri_record(url)
        write_to_card(connection, ndef_record)
        print("URL written to NFC card successfully")
        lock_nfc_tag(connection)

    except NoCardException:
        print("No NFC card found")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error encountered: {e}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: How about an alternative approach, instead of playing around with the lock bits, try setting a password on write access. Then unless you have the password further modification is not possible (so just keep the password secret). But when you are trying to get things right at least you can test multiple times before a Tag becomes unusable.